# Prevent page reload jQuery from only one page of a website

Tags: jquery, html, reload

I am using this jQuery on a website

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var windowWidth = jQuery(window).width();
    jQuery(window).resize(function(){
        if (jQuery(window).width() != windowWidth) {
              windowWidth = jQuery(window).width();
              location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

The purpose is to reload a page when the screen size changes. For example a user is viewing it in portrait mode on a phone then switches to the landscape mode.

But I have one page in the website that I don't want to reload when the screen is resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, the most simplest in my view is that you can define a `boolean` variable on the `window` object such as `window.preventReload` that isn't set to `true` unless in that specific window, and in your `jQuery` code check it before reloading, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var windowWidth = jQuery(window).width();
    jQuery(window).resize(function(){
        if (window.preventReload !== true && jQuery(window).width() != windowWidth) {
              windowWidth = jQuery(window).width();
              location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I want to stop the reload jquery on that page completely(even if changes the screen size) but it should remain functional on all other pages.

Comment: No, I think you misunderstood my answer :)
This code will prevent reloading only in the page that you set `perventReload` to true, and will reload in all other windows.

Comment: Seems I did misunderstood it. Sorry. So, are you saying the I need to add this jquery in that page's code?

Comment: No, you put this code in all of your pages, as you normally was doing it, but in that specific page only add this line: `window.preventRelaod = true;`

Comment: But I don't have that jquery in all my pages and I don't want to edit the code of the pages.

The reload jQuery I am using is coming from custom.js file.

Comment: So you are asking for a pure `javascript` solution that fits only in one file change?

Comment: I don't want to edit the code of all the pages just for stopping the reload function on one page. I have an external js file where I can put the jquery and it'll work from there just like the reload jquery.

Comment: My solution will work if you update that js file only, and the page where you need to stop reload, all other pages will not be touched :)

Comment: Just tried it but it didn't work. The page still reloads.

Comment: How did you add the `window.preventRelaod = true;` to your page?

Comment: I didn't. Where to add that?

Comment: In your html file of the page you don't want to reload, add a `script` tag and put the `window.preventRelaod = true;` in it

Comment: @Rahul Is your problem fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

This will not reload for particular page. For all other pages its reload

```
function getPageName(url) {
    var index = url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
    var filenameWithExtension = url.substr(index);
    var filename = filenameWithExtension.split(".")[0]; // <-- added this line
    return filename;                                    // <-- added this line
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var pagename=getPageName(url);

    if(pagename!="pagenotreload.html"){
      var windowWidth = jQuery(window).width();
      jQuery(window).resize(function(){
        if (jQuery(window).width() != windowWidth) {
              windowWidth = jQuery(window).width();
                            location.reload();
        }
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Do I need to replace URL with page's url ?

Comment: pagenotreload.html this will be changed to your page name.